# What does Unknown Type Selector "button1"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im more of a C++ and plain JS type of dude, and I feel absolutely stupid not being able to find this out.

I tried doing this

```
   <button1 id="coolbutton" type="button">

        My JSFiddle Account

      </button1>
```

along with this CSS code

```
button1 {
  
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: purple;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration-line: overline underline;
}

html {
  
  background-color: #666699;
  
}

body {
  
  background-color: #666699;
}
```

Not feeling so good about my "Epic Coding Skills" because I feel like it's easier than I think.

Comment: What is it that you expect a `<button1>` element to be? The standard button element is `<button>`.

Comment: `button1` is not a valid HTML element. What are you trying to do with that `1`?

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag when I see none? Your CSS and HTML will work fine, even though there's no formal button1 element. And what's giving you that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) defines what element types exist in HTML (along with a format for naming [custom elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name).

It defines, for example, [`button`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element) and [`html`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element). It does not define `button1`, and `button1` does not meet the custom element format.

You have tried to create a `button1` element in your HTML, which is invalid HTML and triggers error recovery in browsers.

You have written a [CSS type selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#type-selectors) to try to select it, and whatever is reporting that error knows you are trying to find an element in an HTML document where `button1` elements are not allowed.

Use `id` and `class` attributes to define specific (or groups of specific) elements. Select the type based on the semantics it has. Don't invent new types.

Comment: Thanks man! Off to keep learning HTML and stuffs. Also, you guys reply fast. I love StackOverflow so much.

Answer (score 1):

there is no `<button1>` element what you are looking for is simply the `<button> </button>`. Do your CSS on the coolButton id (or the id of the button you want to change)